# Jump from override implementation to base/abstract implementation

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Is there a way (which Visual Studio itself provides) to jump from the implementation of a method override in a derived class to the base implementation in the closest base class?

The other way round I can use `Find all references` or `Go To Implementation`.

Comment: It can be done using ReSharper: https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/navigation_search.html